# Does google protocol buffers support size calculation before serialization?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

My (DSP) application produces data at a constant rate. The rate depends on the configuration that is selected by the user. I would like to know how many bytes are generated per second. The data structure contains a repeated (packed) floating point field. The length of the field is constant, but can be changed by the user.

Is there a protocol buffers function that will calculate the message size before serialization?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's impossible to know ahead of time, because protobuf packs the structures it is given into the fewest bytes possible - it won't use four bytes for `int x = 1;` for example - so the library would have to walk the entire graph to know the output size.

I believe you could find this out by doing a serialize operation to a protobuf-compliant stream of your own design that just counts the bytes it is given.  That could be costly, but no more costly than it would be for the library to do that work.

Comment: How can we force it to use 4 bytes for int and do not pack it, to have fixed size serialized data?

Comment: If you serialize the data yourself using the ProtoBuf OutputStream classes you can do this by using the Write methods for each base type rather than varint encoding - see https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding

Answer (score 25):

If you have build the message objects, you can call ByteSize() on the message which returns the number of bytes the serializes message would take up. There is a link to the C++ docs of [ByteSize](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message.ByteSize.details).

Comment: Is there any ByteSize()-like api for python? 

I saw [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/) and I didn't find anything

Comment: For Go there is proto.Size() function: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/proto#Size

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. By "building" the message, serialization is implied. For. eg. if a RepeatedField is present in the message, there is no way ahead of the time, that Protobuf can tell the amount of memory required.

Answer (score 1):

You could fill out the message without sending it and then call [CalculateSize()](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/interface/google/protobuf/i-message#interface_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_i_message_1aa3561db050d542706279ffb6ed9315ad) on it